# Thunderbird 60.0 not showing in Applications Menu after installing tarball

Tags: release-loki, thunderbird

I just installed the latest version of Thunderbird by downloading the archive and following the instructions [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux).

Now, I can open the program by running the script onside the extracted Thunderbird folder. However, it does not show up in my applications menu and the icon is a generic image rather than the Thunderbird logo (as shown in the screenshot). Is there any way to fix this yet?

I'm running elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, btw.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of my dock:]

**Edit: A workaround I found was using AppEditor (from the eOS AppCenter) to create an application icon for Thunderbird. This makes it function like it would normally, including working native notifications.**

**Credit to [blureshadow](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/99yurq/thunderbird_600_not_showing_in_applications_menu/e4redn9) on reddit!**

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found was using AppEditor (from the eOS AppCenter) to create an application icon for Thunderbird. This makes it function like it would normally, including working native notifications.

Credit to [blureshadow](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/99yurq/thunderbird_600_not_showing_in_applications_menu/e4redn9) on reddit!